# Iterator for a custom unbound array

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, std

I implemented my own small `UnboundArray` class:

```
template <typename T>
class UnboundArray {
private:
    std::vector<T> elementData;
public:
    ...
    std::size_t size()
    {
        return elementData.size();
    }
};
```

And I have a class in which I want to use my `UnboundArray`, especially I need to use a for loop on `UnboundArray` elements:

```
for (auto const &row : unbound_arrays) {
// loop over unbound array of unbound arrays and call its size method or something else
}
```

I'm really new to C++ iterators and do not know what path I should follow. Should I implement from scratch my iterator or should I make a member in my `UnboundArray` which is of type `std::iterator`?

Comment: Note that [`std::iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator) have been deprecated, and will be removed sometime in the future. I suggest you check e.g. [this iterator category reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator#Iterator_categories) to see what kind of iterator fits your need best, and what member functions and operator are needed for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mostly need to use a [range based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) with your custom class `UnboundArray`, you might start with implementing `begin()` and `end()` methods for `UnboundArray`:

```
auto begin() { return std::begin(elementData); }
auto end() { return std::end(elementData); }
```

so the loop works:

```
UnboundArray<int> unbound_array;

for (auto const &elem: unbound_array) { // ... }
```

[**wandbox example**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LsHR2NpqJmHuG9Ca)

---

It is important to note that you need `const` overloads in order to iterate through a `const` `UnboundArray`:

```
auto begin() const { return std::cbegin(elementData); }
auto end() const { return std::cend(elementData); }
```

Comment: Thank you, sir! I will check it in a second.

Comment: @Jacobian Do not forget to add the const overloads, ere you get surprised.

Comment: @DeiDei. Could you please elaborate on this in a form of a small answer? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry for a dumb question, but how should I loop through an `unbound_array` instantiated like so: `auto unbound_array = new UnboundArray<int>{};`?

Comment: @Jacobian try dereferencing it: `*unbound_array`